# Run-time Error '438' using .PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a simple Macro to copy data from a closed Excel file into the current one that I have open. So far I have created this

```
    Sub CopyData()

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\sam\Coding\bk.xlsx"

    Dim currentWb As Workbook
    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    currentWb.Activate
    openWb.Activate

    openWs.Range("A1:C2").Copy
    currentWb.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

        openWb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

But I get a RunTime Error 438 and upon debug it highlights the row "currentWb.Range("A1").PasteSpecial". I have search all over the place to find an answer but I haven't been successful. My question is, what am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
currentWb.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

It should be

```
currentWb.Sheets("SomeSheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

replace `xlPasteAll` with whatever you are trying.

`Range` object is not a part of `Workbook` but of `Worksheet`

Also you don't need to use `.Activate`. You code can be written as

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim path As String
    Dim currentWb As Workbook, openWb As Workbook
    Dim currentWs As Worksheet, openWs As Worksheet

    path = "C:\Users\sam\Coding\bk.xlsx"

    Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook
    '~~> Change this applicable
    Set currentWs = currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    openWs.Range("A1:C2").Copy
    currentWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    openWb.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you , the above worked flawlessly. And above all thank you for explaining the reason why my original code did not work. It gave me a clear understanding on how Range works. I do appreciate it.